# Create a object from array of objects by group by value of key called "PageName" in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6, nested-object

Create  a object from array of objects by group by value of key called "PageName" in javascript
Input:

```
[
  {"pagename": "Homepage", "key": "TITLE_HEADER", "value": "Login"},
  {"pagename": "OTPpage", "key": "NAVIGATION_TITLE", "value": "OTP"},
  {"pagename": "Homepage", "key": "SUB_HEADER", "value": "Mobile number"},
  {"pagename": "OTPPage", "key": "TITLE_HEADER", "value": "Login"},
  {"pagename": "RegisterPage", "key": "USERNAME_FIELD", "value": "User name"},
  {"pagename": "Homepage", "key": "SUB_HEADER2", "value": "emailId"},
  {"pagename": "RegisterPage", "key": "PASSWORD_FIELD", "value": "Password"}
]
```

OUT PUT required:(Group by page name)

```
{
    "Homepage":{
        "TITLE_HEADER":"Login",
        "SUB_HEADER":"Mobile number",
        "SUB_HEADER2":""emailId"
    },
    "OTPpage":{
        "NAVIGATION_TITLE":"OTP",
        "TITLE_HEADER":"Login"
    },
    "RegisterPage":{
        "USERNAME_FIELD":"User name",
        "PASSWORD_FIELD":"Password"
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `reduce()`

```js
var list = [
  {"pagename": "Homepage", "key": "TITLE_HEADER", "value": "Login"},
  {"pagename": "OTPpage", "key": "NAVIGATION_TITLE", "value": "OTP"},
  {"pagename": "Homepage", "key": "SUB_HEADER", "value": "Mobile number"},
  {"pagename": "OTPPage", "key": "TITLE_HEADER", "value": "Login"},
  {"pagename": "RegisterPage", "key": "USERNAME_FIELD", "value": "User name"},
  {"pagename": "Homepage", "key": "SUB_HEADER2", "value": "emailId"},
  {"pagename": "RegisterPage", "key": "PASSWORD_FIELD", "value": "Password"}
]

var result = list.reduce((a, v) => {
  a[v.pagename] = a[v.pagename] || {}
  a[v.pagename][v.key] = v.value
  return a
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you can just iterate over it. Something like this:

#### Common `forEach()` solution:

```js
const input = [
  {"pagename": "Homepage", "key": "TITLE_HEADER", "value": "Login"},
  {"pagename": "OTPpage", "key": "NAVIGATION_TITLE", "value": "OTP"},
  {"pagename": "Homepage", "key": "SUB_HEADER", "value": "Mobile number"},
  {"pagename": "OTPpage", "key": "TITLE_HEADER", "value": "Login"},
  {"pagename": "RegisterPage", "key": "USERNAME_FIELD", "value": "User name"},
  {"pagename": "Homepage", "key": "SUB_HEADER2", "value": "emailId"},
  {"pagename": "RegisterPage", "key": "PASSWORD_FIELD", "value": "Password"}
]

const result = {};
input.forEach(row => {
  result[row.pagename] = {...(result[row.pagename] || {}), ...{[row.key]: row.value}}
})
console.log(result);
```

I create empty object `result`, iterate over each `input` and set key by `row.pagename` while i check if `result[row.pagename]` exists by `||` which leads to `{}` if not and then spread it with `{[row.key]: row.value}}` which leads to object merging.

---

### If you would like to use `reduce()`:

```js
let input = [
  {"pagename": "Homepage", "key": "TITLE_HEADER", "value": "Login"},
  {"pagename": "OTPpage", "key": "NAVIGATION_TITLE", "value": "OTP"},
  {"pagename": "Homepage", "key": "SUB_HEADER", "value": "Mobile number"},
  {"pagename": "OTPpage", "key": "TITLE_HEADER", "value": "Login"},
  {"pagename": "RegisterPage", "key": "USERNAME_FIELD", "value": "User name"},
  {"pagename": "Homepage", "key": "SUB_HEADER2", "value": "emailId"},
  {"pagename": "RegisterPage", "key": "PASSWORD_FIELD", "value": "Password"}
]

const result = input.reduce((accumulator, row) => {
  accumulator[row.pagename] = {...(accumulator[row.pagename] || {}), ...{[row.key]: row.value}};
  return accumulator;
}, {})

console.log(result);
```